# Why do I need to use latin-1 instead of utf-8 when using python with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, python, analogwrite

When reading and writing with a python serial port connection to arduino, if I don't use latin-1 ('ISO-8859-1'), the results are not as expected. Like if I have

```
int outP = 5;
//...
int outV = Serial.read();
analogWrite(outP, outV);
```

While with python I have

```
serial_port.write(chr(255).encode())
```

I read 3.78 V from the pin, whereas if I use

```
serial_port.write(chr(255).encode(encoding = 'latin-1'))
```

I get 5.04 V. I have read latin-1 and utf-8 don't always match, but is there something about arduino that requires using latin-1? Of course, these return different values when testing each encoding, using 255 gives b'\xc3\xbf' (from 'Ã¿') with utf-8 or b'\xff' from ('ÿ') with latin-1, but why does arduino work with latin-1?

FYI other options that work are

```
v = 255

serial_port.write(v.to_bytes(1, byteorder = 'big'))

serial_port.write(bytes[v])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is there something about arduino that requires using latin-1?

No, not really.

What it comes down to is that `Serial.read()` reads bytes, irrespective of whatever encoding they may be being used with.  ISO-8859 only encodes character code points in the 0-255 range, so when you choose a 0-255 code point and send it as ISO-8859, it gets sent as 1 byte, which is how you're code has been written to receive it.

A 255 code point as utf-8 would require multiple bytes to encode and so would result in multiple `Serial.read()` calls for a given value.

If you open a python3 REPL and put `chr(255).encode()` or more explicitly `chr(255).encode('utf-8')` you will see it results in `b'\xc3\xbf'`.  So on the Arduino side you will see this as two separate `Serial.read()` results, `0xC3` and `0xBF`.

When you're just taking in strings and UTF-8 and splatting them out via `Serial.println()`, the Arduino is blissfully unaware of that they're UTF-8 and not ISO-8859.  Really you could use any encoding you wanted, the the caveat being that if you're using c-strings to store them, the encoding would need to be one that doens't allow for a single null byte to be in the middle of the string.

---

You may want to look into using [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) rather than cobbling together python bytestrings with sequences of `chr()` and `.encode(whatever)`. `struct.pack` will also result in a bytestring, but it's more purpose built for doing this.

You can `import struct` and then `struct.pack('B', 255)` will result in `b'\xff` same as `chr(255).encode('iso8859-1')`, but at least expresses intent.  `'B'` here signifies an `unsigned char` range, you'll find the format specifiers in the documentation. You'll get a greater benefit when you begin using multiple fields where `struct.pack` will be a lot less unwieldy than the `chr` and `encode` and string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, ```len(chr(255).encode(encoding = 'latin-1'))``` returns 1, while ```len(chr(255).encode())``` returns 2

Comment: ok thanks, what format should be used with struct.pack?

Comment: I have migrated my previous comment into the answer and addressed your question there.